# Issue with CSS drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having a CSS issue with a drop down menu in my site. The url is:
http://www.juneehee.com/ProductTypeView.aspx?TypeID=2

As you can see the sub-category (bags & purses,Artworks, etc), the dropdown works perfectly for the first rows, but for the 2nd row sub-category (for example: Calligraphy), the drop down menu overlaps with the sub-category itself. I cant find why its happening. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav-category {
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
float:left;
width:750px;
border:1px solid;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:40px;
}



.nav-category .Categorypanel
{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:auto;
height:auto;

}


.nav-category ul {

list-style:none;
font-family:"Century Gothic";
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:normal;

}

.nav-category ul li {
float:left;
margin-right:35px;}

.nav-category ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #424242;
font-size:12px;}

.nav-category ul li a:hover {
color:#666;}

.nav-category ul li ul { display:none; top:20px; position:absolute; left:auto;}



.nav-category li ul li {
line-height:15px; margin-left:5px; padding:3px;} 

.nav-category ul li ul li a { font-size:11px;}

.nav-category ul li:hover ul, li.over ul { display:block;position:absolute; background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ebebeb; white-space:nowrap; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0; padding-left:0}

.nav-category ul li:hover li { float:none; letter-spacing:0px;margin:0px 0 0 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'm noticing is that they appear to be set with absolute positioning, 20px from the top.  The absolute positioning will be determined from their relatively positioned container (#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlCategory) so if the content wraps down to a second (or third, or fourth, etc) line then the drop downs will still appear at the same vertical; relative to their parent container, not the respective "parent" drop down menu item.

Comment: Thank you Mike. You are right. But only setting the positioning to relative does not do the trick. I also had to set margin-top to 20px. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer IF you feel it effectively addresses your question ;-)  Glad you got it worked out, nahid.